# JS: drag and drop image on another image

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to be able to drag and drop - and as a result of this operation overlay one image on top of another. They are transparent images.

But whenever I attempt to do this, the first image is disappearing.
Any suggestions?

```
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It disappears because you use `ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));`.

Each element can exist in the DOM only in a single instance. Doing `appendChild` to existing element you extract it from the place it is now. If you wish to copy element - you need to do it explicit, with `cloneNode` method, for example.

```
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode());
```